# Local Gem Causes Heroku Push to Fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, heroku, rubygems, bundler

I have a Gem on my local machine that I declare in my Gem file like this:

group :assets do
   gem 'my_gem', path: "/Users/me/path/to/my_gem"
end

This works great locally, but when I push to staging on Heroku, the build fails because the gem isn't available.

Currently I'm having to comment/uncomment this gem between deploys which is a real pain.

I've also tried adding it to my development group, but this doesn't help.

**Why is Heroku looking for this gem?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bundler always needs to resolve all of the gems in your Gemfile. You shouldn't commit a Gemfile that contains a local path.

Instead, push your gem to a git repository that is reachable from Heroku and point to that in your Gemfile.

For development, you can use a local path override: http://bundler.io/v1.3/git.html#local

Answer (score 1):

you can try placing the gem in `vendor/gems` directory, create it if it doesn't exist.then in your Gemfile do like this:

```
gem 'rails_multisite', path: 'vendor/gems/rails_multisite'
```

and make sure you run `bundle update` so Heroku can Pickup the changes